# Associate JTable cell with action

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, cell

In a JTable I have JButtons as table cells. Each specific button should start a different action. How can I do that? The actions are defined by me.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you read about TableCellEditors?

Comment: how are you putting the buttons in the cells? With a renderer?

Comment: This is not, typically, how tables work.  Have a look at [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) for some ideas.

Comment: @Oliver Watkins : yes, with a Renderer:

Comment: I used a method to associate a button with an action, but since the button is seen as a table cell, nothing happens when the button is clicked...

Comment: @user2044918, you ignored comments by Stanislav and MadProgrammer which both suggest using a cell editor (which is the way to solve your problem). Instead you have concentrated on the renderer, which will never work.

Answer (score -1):

Have you thought about just adding your actions to your buttons inside the renderer?

```
public class MyRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {


    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
        JTable table, Object color,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
        int row, int column) {

        if (some_condition) {

            JButotn b1 = new JButton('A')

            b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    //do stuff
                }
            }

            return b1;
        }else if (some__other_condition) {
            JButotn b2 = new JButton('B')

            b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    //do stuff
                }
            }

            return b2;
        }
    }
}
```

Its probably not the most correct way of doing things performance wise, but without knowing more about your application I can't help much more than that.

Comment: -1, you would never use a renderer for this. A renderer is used to render the cell. The renderer is called when Swing determines a cell needs to be painted. For example when you select a row (or unselect a row) the cell needs to be painted. So you have no control over when this method is invoked. A renderer is not a real component so even if you use the button to render the cell you can't just add an ActionListener to it.This type of functionality is cotrolled by the editor, because the editor is invoked by the user.

Comment: you could argue that a button shouldn't belong in a renderer or an editor, since a button does not represent the change of state or value of a cell. A text field , checkbox or datepicker on other hand change a value. Button does not fit into either of these categories.